# Spatial probit matrix R

Tags: r, spatial

I try to use spatialprobit model in R. I have 83 regions and dataframe 125360 x 13 shape.
Following code give me an error:

```
    sarprobit.fit1 <- sarprobit(MALOIM_6 ~ 
                 region_money+number_child + VZR_NRAB_c +   
                 R_2_0 + R_5_2 + PENS_c + INV_c +   R_1_1+NP_SEM + 
                 R_1_1_1, sparsematrix, df_probit)

**Error: Matrices must have same dimensions in .Arith.Csparse(e1, 
e2, .Generic, class. = "dgCMatrix")**
```

How to deal with it?
I create matrix by following code:

```
geo_data <- raster::getData('GADM', country = 'Russia', 
level = 1)[, c('NL_NAME_1')]
coords<- coordinates(geo_data)
nb <- knearneigh(coords, k = 3) %>% knn2nb()
listw <- nb2listw(nb,style='W', zero.policy=TRUE)
W <- listw2mat(listw)
sparsematrix <- as(matrix(W), "sparseMatrix")
```